# Where can I find resources for a clean, well-designed widget like Calendar?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I'm writing an App Widget and want it to have a clean, simple style like the Android Calendar:
http://justanothermobilemonday.com/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/DSC_0012_thumb.jpg

I've been hunting around the AOSP but I can't find the resources I need. Can anyone point me to a source for a layout and related bitmaps? I'm keen to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the primary resource, the XML layout for the Calendar widget, which references the other resources:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/froyo-release/res/layout/agenda_appwidget.xml